# How to implement Version Control in Java Serialization Using Same SerialUid?

Tags: java, serialization, version-control

I have following class that implements serialization.

```
class User implements Serializable{

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String username;
    String password;

}
```

I try to save the User class object in a text file with following code.Basically I try to write the object and then read it.

```
public class SerializableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User("userB","passwordB");

        String filename = "E:\\Proj-docs\\userFile.txt";

         FileOutputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file); 

            out.writeObject(user); 

            out.close(); 
            file.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        User user2=null;

        try {
            FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file2);


            user2= (User) in.readObject();


            Optional checkNull = Optional.ofNullable(user2);
            if(checkNull.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(user2.username + " "+user2.password);

            }else {
                System.out.println("Null Object");
            }

        }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

it gives the output `userB passwordB`
Now let's say I want to change my user object and store it in that same text file

```
public class SerializableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User("userD","passwordD");
        String filename = "E:\\Proj-docs\\userFile.txt";

         FileOutputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file); 

            out.writeObject(user); 
            out.close(); 
            file.close(); 
            :
            :
            :
```

Now if I read my User object it gives `userD passwordD`

My question is even after updating my user is there a way I can retrieve the old version of user (one with values `userB passwordB`) using serialVersionUID ? I want to see how version control can be used in Java serialization when we are updating the object or adding new attributes to our class and not changing serial uid.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Java serialization does not help you here. It (and basically all other serialization formats) only capture a snapshot state of your object. If you want to maintain a version history of object state as it changes over time, you have to implement that yourself (basically writing multiple snapshots and/of diffs of snapshots).

Comment: Thanks for the input. is there a way can I use a custom version history feature in above code?